# É possível fazer requisição HTTP(POST, GET...) com android para qualquer domínio?

Tags: php, android, http, request

Tenho um back-end com PHP com URLS que retornam dados para meu front-end com Angular. Funciona normalmente pois estão no mesmo domínio. No caso de um app android que está fora do domínio, terei problemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terá, mas não por causa do Android, e sim por causa do seu servidor que precisará estar configurado para aceitar conexões de outros domínios. Essa é então uma dúvida mais relativa ao PHP do que ao Android.

O Android só vai precisar ter a permissão para efetuar uma conexão remota no `AndroidManifest.xml`.